# How to updateMultiple documents in mongoose base on current value of document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following mongodb model:

```
const schema = new Schema({
  timezone: {
   type: String,
  },
  datetimeBaseOnTimezone: {
   type: Date,
  }
})
```

I want to update the **datetimeBaseOnTimezone** with the current Date for each document in database based on the current timezone of each document this using a single query.

Something like this:

```
  await Model.updateMany({},(element) => ({
      datetimeBaseOnTimezone: new Date(new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: element.timezone }))
  }));
```

Is there any solution similar to this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a few assumptions:

- the `datetimeBaseOnTimezone` string has the same format for all documents
- the `timezone` string contains an Olson timezone identifier or a UTC offset
- you are using MongoDB 4.2 or newer

You could use the pipeline form of [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/), along with the [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) operator, which might look something like:

```
Model.updateMany({},[{$set:{datetimeBaseOnTimezone:{$dateFromString:{
   dateString:"$datetimeBaseOnTimezone",
   format: <see dateFromString docs>,
   timezone: "$timezone",
   onError: "$datetimeBaseOnTimezone",
   onNull: "$datetimeBaseOnTimezone"
}}}])
```